# Disable converting WebVTT-content into lowercase (video.js)

Tags: video.js, typography

I'm using video.js for subtitles and chapters but in the player the labels are converted into lowercase while in the .vtt-files and html-tags it's written different.
For example in the track-element I wrote

```
<track src="vtt/1Startseite.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" label="Deutsch" default>
```

but in the player the label is written "deutsch".

(same for the whole chapter labels)

How can I prevent video.js from doing this?

Thanks in advance,
Marco.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, 
it's in the video-js.css:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-menu-button ul li { ... text-transform: lowercase;}
```

so just setting in to

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-menu-button ul li { ... text-transform: none;}
```

will fix it, same for chapter titles.

Got an answer on Github, where it's called a "just a style thing", see here: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1636